# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed in cross correlation

Tags: c++, opencv

I am getting this error when I try to run my code:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (corrsize.height <= img.rows +
>   templ.rows - 1 && corrsize.width <= img.cols + templ.cols - 1) in
>   crossCorr, file
>   /Users/ts/documents/opencv-3.0.0-beta/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp,
>   line 658 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   cv::Exception:
>   /Users/ts/documents/opencv-3.0.0-beta/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp:658:
>   error: (-215) corrsize.height <= img.rows + templ.rows - 1 &&
>   corrsize.width <= img.cols + templ.cols - 1 in function crossCorr

here is the source code:

```
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

/// Global Variables

Mat img; Mat templ; 
Mat result;
const char* image_window = "Source Image";
const char* result_window = "Result window";

int match_method;
int max_Trackbar = 5;

/// Function Headers
void MatchingMethod( int, void* );

/**
* @function main
*/

 int main( int, char** argv )
 {

 /// Load image and template

 img = imread( argv[1], 1);
 templ = imread( argv[2], 1);

/// Create windows
namedWindow( image_window, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
namedWindow( result_window, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

/// Create Trackbar
const char* trackbar_label = "Method: \n 0: SQDIFF \n 1: SQDIFF NORMED \n      2: TM CCORR \n 3: TM CCORR NORMED \n 4: TM COEFF \n 5: TM COEFF NORMED";
createTrackbar( trackbar_label, image_window, &match_method, max_Trackbar, MatchingMethod );

MatchingMethod( 0, 0 );

waitKey(0);
return 0;
}

/**
* @function MatchingMethod
* @brief Trackbar callback
*/

void MatchingMethod( int, void* )
{

/// Source image to display
Mat img_display;
img.copyTo( img_display );

/// Create the result matrix
int result_cols =  img.cols - templ.cols + 1;
int result_rows = img.rows - templ.rows + 1;

result.create( result_rows, result_cols, CV_32FC1 );

/// Do the Matching and Normalize
matchTemplate( img, templ, result, match_method );
normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

/// Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
double minVal; double maxVal; Point minLoc; Point maxLoc;
Point matchLoc;

minMaxLoc( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat() );


/// For SQDIFF and SQDIFF_NORMED, the best matches are lower values. For all the other methods, the higher the better
if( match_method  == TM_SQDIFF || match_method == TM_SQDIFF_NORMED )
{ matchLoc = minLoc; }
else
{ matchLoc = maxLoc; }

/// Show me what you got
rectangle( img_display, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols , matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0 );
rectangle( result, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols , matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0 );

imshow( image_window, img_display );
imshow( result_window, result );

return;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to allocate space for `result`. Try removing `result.create( result_rows, result_cols, CV_32FC1 )`

Comment: I tried what you said but am still getting the same error

Comment: Which line in your code gives you the Exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure the images are loaded correctly by `cv::imread()`? Is it working if you give the full path instead of the values of `argv`?

i.e.:

```
img = imread("C:/original_image.jpg");
templ = imread("C:/template_image.jpg");
```

Comment: I did give the full path and now am getting this inline error: inline
void Mat::create(int _rows, int _cols, int _type)
{
    _type &= TYPE_MASK;
    if( dims <= 2 && rows == _rows && cols == _cols && type() == _type && data )
        return;
    int sz[] = {_rows, _cols};
    create(2, sz, _type);//its indicating here
}OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (s >= 0) in setSize, file /Users/ts/documents/opencv-3.0.0-beta/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 290
for both images